# jQuery: Changing sliding div position depending on scroll position

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, slide

Trying to have a hidden div slide down or up when hovering over an element. Div sliding down/up must adjust position depending on scroll position. Any help?

Here is some of my existing code

```
$(".team-box").hover(function () { $(".side-top").show(); 
if ($(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height() < $(this).offset().top){ 
    $(".slide-top").css({top: "-130%"}); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked? If you post your code and explain where you are having trouble, you're more likely to get better help at StackOverflow.

Comment: $(".team-box").hover(function () {
        $(".side-top").show();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height() < $(this).offset().top) {
            $(".slide-top").css({top: "-130%"});
        }